# How do I do api in Rails 4? Rails-api gem is merged in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-api

I already have a Rails 4 website.
Now I'm building a mobile app and need to get data from the the same database my website is using.

It looks like rails-api gem is merged in Rails 5. But Rails 5 is not production-ready yet and is not supported by such gems as devise.

Docs are all on merged version:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

So which gem and guide should I use to create an api for my website at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in Rails 4 that prevents you from building an API. Why not create an API in your existing Rails app under a namespace? There are some gems like [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) that can help, but they're not necessary. There are many tutorials on the topic including some Rails Casts that are still relevant, so it should be easy.

The Rails API gem is a lighter version of Rails that is stripped down to only the core parts that an API app needs. This means you don't have ActionView or server generated templates. It's basically Rails minus anything that an API doesn't need.

By being merged into Rails 5, it simply means that Rails 5 will give you the option to create a stripped-down app that only has what an API app needs (minus ActionView and other cruft).

But everything inside of Rails API is inside Rails and more.

But since you already have a Rails app running, just build the API into it. If you want to create an API only app, then go ahead and create one using either the Rails API gem, a normal Rails app, or even Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an api on your own without any gem doing api. Try to follow some examples like: [Building a RESTful API in a Rails Application](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application) and others.